# Изменить JSON-файл из JS?

Tags: javascript, json

Мне нужно изменить содержание JSON файла без бэкенда. Хочу напрямую из javascript-файла это сделать. Возможно ли это?

Comment: это не возможно без бэкэнда..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотря что считать бэкендом и файлом.

Можно сохранить в `localStorage`.

Если JSON разделяемый с другими пользователями -- сервер всё равно нужен.

Можно настроить WebDAV, получится с сервером но без кода (хотя с кодом проще).

Можно посмотреть облачные сервисы -- тоже сервер реально есть, но у нас нет.